# Find Covariance

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that we are interested in the relationship between the age of the individuals who are members of our managed- care organization and the use of physician care, as measured by visits. Suppose also that after selecting 15 members at random we obtained the following paired observations

Visits: 3 5 4 2 1 3 6 7 4 5 10 1 2 3 8
Age:    28 45 50 19 16 27 54 63 32 42 68 19 23 30 61

Use the data to find the covariance between age and the number of visits

Comment: We calculate the covariance as $\text{Cov}(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$. What do you get when you plug in the values?

Comment: Can you please elaborate Sire so i can vote you? It will be a great favor from you. Thanks

Comment: there are many values of X as well as of Y. Which should i put?

Comment: "there are many values of X as well as of Y. Which should i put?" All of them?  Why wouldn't you use all the data?

Comment: actually i am having a little confusion sir. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E[X]$ refers to the mean of the values for $X$; here, we can let $X$ represent the ages of the patients. $E[Y]$, then, will be used for the number of visits.

The one that may be tricky is $E[XY]$.  This stands for the mean of the products of corresponding data points.  That is, take the first $x$, $28$, and the first $y$, $3$, and multiply them together:  You get $84$. Do the same with the second pair, $45$ and $5$: You get $225$. Do this for all $15$ pairs of numbers and find the mean.

Finally, plug the three numbers you ended up with into the formula I gave you and see what you get.  If the digits before the decimal point add up to $4$, you probably got it.  (Feel free to post your answer, though, and I'll confirm.)

Comment: answer comes out to be 95.7?

Comment: @hani: No, here's what I meant by the digits summing to $4$: For the answer you gave, the digits would sum to $16$. What did you get for the mean of $X$ and the mean of $Y$?

Comment: x comes out to be 38.2 and y comes out to be 4.26

Comment: @hani: 4.26 is correct, but 38.2 is slightly off. However, that wouldn't account for the large difference between 95.7 and the actual answer; that means your value for $E[XY]$ is off as well. Check your work for both of these parts; I find it helpful to create a table for all the $xy$ values.

Comment: value of x comes out to be 38.46. So E[X]E[Y]=163.868?

Comment: @hani: Okay, now make sure everything is in order for $E[XY]$...

Comment: answer is 40.79?

Comment: @hani: I got $40.54\bar{2}$. Check your work again; you're almost there...

Comment: yeah i found my mistake. Thanks a lot Sire for your kind help.